# C# name does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, forms, variables

I have a `Class` and a `Form`. This is the code I have in my form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Tamagotchi
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label3.Text = "doplntamboredom";
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label6.Text = GetMood();
        }
    }
}
```

That last part (`label6.Text = GetMood()`) is making error:

> The name 'GetMood' does not exist in the current context.

And this is the code I have in my class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Tamagotchi
{
    class Mazlicek
    {
        private int hunger = 1;
        private int boredom = 1;

        private string mood;
        public string GetMood()
        {
             return mood;
        }

        private void Moods(int hunger, int boredom, string strHunger, string strBoredom)
        {
            if ((boredom + hunger) > 15)
            {
                mood = "Angry!";
            }
            else if ((boredom + hunger) > 10 && (boredom + hunger) < 15)
            {
                mood = "Frustrated..";
            }
            else if ((boredom + hunger) > 5 && (boredom + hunger) < 11)
            {
                mood = "Fine.";
            }
            else
            {
                mood = "Happy!";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I have no idea why there is this problem. I'm making it with Visual Studio 2015 and it is all in one project.

Comment: Where is your instance of `Mazlicek` in your form? Why are you trying to call `GetMood` from a place where it is not defined?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/x9afc042(v=vs.110).aspx read this as well as this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx

Comment: @GrantWinney...Although the `Moods` method is private but I think he didn't use the `Moods` in  the `Form1`. He just wants to return `mood` from `GetMood` method. So I think it would be better  if he use *properties* for this purpose as I said in my answer. What about that?

Answer (score 4):

You probably mean to have an instance of `Mazlicek` in your form. In that way you can call methods on it.

So, start by instantiating the variable `mazlicek` to an instance of type `Mazlicek`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Mazlicek mazlicek = new Mazlicek();

    ...
}
```

Now we have an instantiated object, you can can call methods on it and set properties to remember its state. You have to reference it by its variable name `mazlicek`:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label6.Text = mazlicek.GetMood();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
label6.Text = Mazlicek.GetMood();
```

and change it to

```
static class Mazlicek
```

and

```
private static string mood;
```

and

```
public static string GetMood()
{
    return mood;
}
```

Comment: No; he probably should have an instance.

Comment: But there's no constructor... Maybe it's static?

Comment: But the way he calls `GetMood` seems like it's static

Comment: Why, because he doesn't use `this`? `this` isn't required.

Comment: if it isn't static it should be `mood.GetMood()` Something like this.

Comment: @J3soon the OP probably should create an Instance of the class